# Warning (Code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: '20120801' for function str_to_date for YYYYMMDD Format

Tags: mysql

```
select STR_TO_DATE('20120801', 'YYYYMMDD');

+-------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('20120801', 'YYYYMMDD') |
+-------------------------------------+
| NULL                                |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Warning (Code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: '20120801' for function str_to_date
```

I am not following what syntax error is present in the String date or the date format YYYYMMDD?

Comment: I think I found the answer in the documentation of the function. Unsure how to close this question. This link provides a good explanation of formatting rules [link](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date)  code should be :  select STR_TO_DATE('20120801', '%Y%m%d');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding %

```
select STR_TO_DATE('20120801', '%Y%m%d');
```

Answer (score 3):

The date format should be `%Y%m%d`. See [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)